Where's the barycenter of a hydrogen or helium atom?
Where's a hydrogen atom's nucleus-electron barycenter with respect to the nucleus? How about helium's nucleus-electron barycenter?

Every electron orbital is symmetric about the nucleus, no?

What information leads you to believe that the barycenter isn’t just on the nucleus somewhere (knowing that electrons fill orbitals)? See RC_23’s comment; all orbitals are symmetric about the nucleus so the electrons can be, in terms of barycenter calculations, be ignored.

Well, $s$ orbitals are symmetric at the minimum and that is all we worry about here.

The barycenter depends on relative masses of the objects and the distance between them relative to the radius of the massive object. For example: the Earth-moon barycenter is within the Earth, whereas the sun-Jupiter barycenter is outside the sun. I suppose the nucleus-electron barycenter is within the nucleus owing the large mass discrepancy.
